# Why this code prints an infinite amount of "What's your guess?"

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to make a number guessing game between the range from 1 to 100. The program will stop if the user guesses the correct number.

My current code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What's your guess? ");
        int n = reader.nextInt();
        reader.close();

    int Number = randomNumber.nextInt(100 + 1);
    int guess = n;
     while (guess != Number) {
        System.out.println("What's your guess? ");
        new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    if (guess == Number) {
        System.out.println("Your have guessed the correct number! ");
    }

    else if (guess < Number) {
        System.out.println("Your number is too low! ");
    }

    else if (guess > Number) {
        System.out.println("Your number is too high! ");
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: You are not reading new inputs from the user inside your loop

Comment: maybe because inside the while loop you're not changing the values of the variables Number and guess?

Comment: the if/elseif/else if nos inside the while loop, and you're not rading input, read tutos about read from Scanner

Comment: Also don't close a `Scanner` unless you don't need it **and** it's underlying inputsream anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is where using the formatter in your IDE is helpful. You would be able to see that the if conditions which are after the loop should be inside the loop and you should be reading the reading the guess from input.

BTW You should never close the input unless you explicitly don't want to read anything from it ever again.

try

```
 Random randomNumber = new Random();
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
 int number = randomNumber.nextInt(100 + 1);
 while(true) {
    System.out.println("What's your guess? ");
    int guess = reader.nextInt();

    if (guess == Number) {
        System.out.println("You have guessed the correct number! ");
        break; // no need to guess more

    } else if (guess < Number) {
        System.out.println("Your number is too low! ");

    } else if (guess > Number) {
        System.out.println("Your number is too high! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things I like to mention in addition. The call to [`Scanner#close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) does close the InputStream as well. Once `System.in` is closed it cannot be opened again so be careful when to close the scanner. The 2nd thing I'd like to see in this answer is the proper way/time to close the Scanner. Anyway +1

Comment: @L.Spillner I don't feel there is ever a good time to close the input (or output) unless there is a very specific reason to do so.

Comment: I agree. But still in my opinion it's good practice to close resources when no longer needed ( to prevent resource leaks ). In this specific case it would be the termination of the application (in which case the OS normally cleans up everything). That point is just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @L.Spillner my inclination is to only include which is actually needed, which the environment won't do for you for free anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop to

```
while (guess != Number) {
    if (guess == Number) {
     System.out.println("Your have guessed the correct number! ");
     break;
    }

    else if (guess < Number) {
     System.out.println("Your number is too low! ");
    }

    else if (guess > Number) {
     System.out.println("Your number is too high! ");
    }

    System.out.println("Guess Again?");
    guess = reader.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is infinite loop. Also, you should avoid using 'Number' as variable name as there is a class in java with the same name `java.lang.Number`. You can also need any number of variables using single object of Scanner class. So, a cleaner code would look like this :

```
while (guess != number) {
        System.out.println("What's your guess? ");
        guess = reader.nextInt();
    }
```

Now, if you solve above problems, your code will never go to the two else-if blocks, because by the time your while loop breaks you will have 'guess' always be equal to 'number'. I think what you are trying to achieve here is :

```
while (guess != number) {
    System.out.println("What's your guess? ");
    guess = reader.nextInt();

    if (guess == number) {
        System.out.println("Your have guessed the correct number! ");
    }

    else if (guess < number) {
        System.out.println("Your number is too low! ");
    }

    else if (guess > number) {
        System.out.println("Your number is too high! ");
    }
}
```